# express-debug "cannot find stack"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to profile a simple express application.  When I run node it responds with

```
throw new Error('Cannot find stack');
      ^
Error: Cannot find stack
```

Here's the code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
require('express-debug')(app, {});
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.send("Hello world!");
});
app.get("/other", function(request, response) {
    var message = "";
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 10000; ++ii) {
         message = message + "x";
    }
    response.send(message);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve your problem you must call express-debug after your routes, for example:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var debug = require('express-debug')
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.send("Hello world!");
});
app.get("/other", function(request, response) {
    var message = "";
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 10000; ++ii) {
         message = message + "x";
    }
    response.send(message);
});

debug(app, {});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: This got it serving but doesn't only shows locals and software info.  No profiling.  I tried setting the panels to "profile" but it gave an error on launch about an undefined "stack.length".